# php print each line from textarea

Tags: php

i have  this code

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"  type="text" name="ytburl" /></textarea>       
<input type="submit" value="START" name="submit" />

$ytburl = $_POST["ytburl"];
echo 'link '.$ytburl.' is here'
```

so if in textarea i put 2 links:

example.com/11111

example.com/22222

then i get this output:

*link example.com/11111 example.com/22222 is here*

i want to get this output:

**link example.com/11111 is here**

**link example.com/22222 is here**

Comment: You can use regular expressions, Check this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just print text like it was sent you can use `nl2br()` function to replace all new line characters to HTML tags.

But it's not best idea to just print data unfiltered so combine it with `strip_tags()` function.

```
echo nl2br(strip_tags($variable));
```

Comment: if i add 3 lines 111 222 333 then your code echo "".nl2br(strip_tags($variable))."test"; shows 111 222 333 test, so i want to be like this 111 test 222 test 333 test

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$arrLines = explode(' ', $variable);
foreach($arrLines AS $line){
    echo $line . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: if i add 3 lines 111 222 333  then  your code    echo $line . 'test';  shows  111 222 333 test, so i want  to be like this 111 test 222 test 333 test